# Tracking downloads with WHMCS

Tags: php, hook, whmcs

I'm trying to track which files have been downloaded by which users.

I'm using this action hook to track the downloads:  http://docs.whmcs.com/Hooks:FileDownload

Here's the code I have for my action hook:

```
<?php
add_hook("FileDownload",0,"track_FileDownload","");

function track_FileDownload($vars)
{
    logactivity("File Downloaded");
}
?>
```

Right now it's displaying this in my activity log:

```
File Downloaded
```

But what I would like is for the log to also display the title of the file that was downloaded, like this:

```
File Downloaded - Name Of File
```

Does anyone know how to do this or if it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

According to hook documentation, you can read $_REQUEST variables.
the download ID is $_REQUEST['id'], to read download title:

```
function track_FileDownload() {

    $logText = 'File Downloaded';

    $id = filter_var($_REQUEST['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if ($id > 0) {

        $rs = select_query('tbldownloads', 'title', array('id' => $id));
        if ($rw = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $logText .= ' - ' . $rw['title'];
        }
    }

    logactivity($logText);

}
```